# RPC(Remote Procedure Call) vs ORB(Object Request Broker) What is the difference and what is the relation with RMI

Tags: middleware, rpc, distributed-system, idl

From what I know:

- RPC (Remote Procedure Call) which uses the IDL (Interface Description Language) as its contract provides methods that can be called by a client. So, the client calls these methods for example (add()) using client Stub, and the server receives the request calls the add() function and returns the answer to the client Stub
- ORB (Object Request Broker) is very similar to RPC but uses the object semantic for example I can create a Calculator Object. and objects are reusable outside the main code

Now for example if I am using RMI(Remote Method Invocation) I use classes and an Interface as a contract. So this makes RMI an ORB technology?

Are these Statements true :

- When we use IDL in a distributed environment technology it's RPC and when we use Interfaces and Object Oriented approach we are using ORB?
- ORB and RPC are concepts and their applications in real life are RMI CORBA DCOM SunRPC ONC-RPC?

Thanks in advance